# Replace "." by ")" after section number

Tags: sectioning, numbering, koma-script, section-titles

I'm using KOMA script's `scrartcl` class and have customized the section numbering as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\alph{section}}
    \section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the output:
[image: a. Introduction]

Now I'd like to replace the dot character after the section number (".") by a closing parenthesis (")"). The best solution I've found so far is:

```
\renewcommand\sectionformat{\thesection)\enskip}
```

which results in
[image: a) Introduction].

However, I'm wondering if this way is recommendable or if there is a more canonical way to do it. Especially, I'd like to just change the character in question without touching the horizontal spacing or prefix and in the best case I'd like to be able to change multiple levels (section, subsection, paragraph etc.) at once.

Comment: Maybe see the titlesec package...?

Comment: There's always the option of using patchcmd or similar, but that doesn't seem good either.

Comment: Changing `\sectionformat` is the way to go with `scrartcl`, which has been incompatible with `titlesec` for a few years.

Answer (score 1):

The komascript classes offer the choice of having a period after all sectional numbers or not. By default they follow Duden's recommendation that all numeric labels aren't followed by a period, nonnumeric are.

At least this is what the manual says, but isn't what actually happens: maybe I don't read correctly the manual.

If you're bold, you can redefine the meaning of `\autodot`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\autodot{\if@altsecnumformat)\fi}
\makeatother
```

Full example.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\alph{section}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\autodot{\if@altsecnumformat)\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\subsection{Another}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But the real solution is indeed to use `\sectionformat`. You can read in the manual (page 110 of the current version) that the standard format for all sectional titles (from `\section` down) is to have `\enspace` between the number (possibly followed by a period) and the title.

So indeed

```
\sectionformat{\thesection)\enspace}
```

is the way to go. You need to change *all* levels, though, there is no generic setting.

Comment: 997k -- you are really close! Will there be a party at 1M?

Comment: @KeksDose Big party!

Comment: sir @egreg Kindly include me also into the party.... :-D

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is ok, but maybe you have more levels to change and if, you might want a table of contents and so on.

So let's extend your MWE to a whole document, using the blindtext package:

```
\documentclass[ngerman, numbers=nodotatend]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext, lmodern}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\alph{section})}
%\renewcommand\sectionformat{\thesection)\enskip}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Result (only part of first page):
[image: pic of page]

The renewcommand would add the ")" only to the heading, but not to the TOC.

If you need to redefine more of the headings, please have a closer look into the manual, sect. 21.8, regarding "\DeclareSectionCommand[Einstellungen ]{Name }" (german version, `texdoc scrguide`on command line, english version `texdoc scrguien`).